# i want to use this id route to insert into my value form @Route("/offrerecla/recl/{id}"

Tags: php, symfony

```
/**
 * @Route("/offrerecla/recl/{id}", name="reclamation_new", methods={"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function nerjj(Request $request, ReclamationRepository $reclamationRepository): Response
{

    $reclamation = new Reclamation();

    $form = $this->createForm(ReclamationType::class, $reclamation);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $reclamationRepository->add($reclamation);
        return $this->redirectToRoute('reclamations_moi', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
    }

    return $this->render('home/reclamer_off.html.twig', [
        'reclamation' => $reclamation,
        'form' => $form->createView(),

    ]);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeZpt.png)

Comment: <tr>
            <td>{{ form_label(form.offreareclamer,"Offre a reclamer" ) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_widget(form.offreareclamer ) }}</td>
            <td><span style="color:red">{{ form_errors(form.offreareclamer ) }}</span></td>
        </tr>

Comment: #@Route("/offrerecla/recl/{id}" i want to use the id value for this form see the photo posted to more information  {{ form_widget(form.offreareclamer ) }} i hope you understand my problem im sorry i m not good in english and thnx

Comment: Could you show your ReclamationType class?

Comment: @Marleen this is my ReclamationType class ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to show the `id` from the url in the `offreareclamer` field of your form.
Your form is bound to the `Reclamation` class, and the `offreareclamer` field is bound to the `Offre` class.

If you fetch the `Offre` entity with the `id` from the url, and set that onto the empty `Reclamation` class that you're passing into the form, it should show the correct id in the form:

```
/**
 * @Route("/offrerecla/recl/{id}", name="reclamation_new", methods={"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function nerjj(Request $request, ReclamationRepository $reclamationRepository, Offre $offre): Response
{

    $reclamation = new Reclamation();
    $reclamation->setOffre($offre);

    $form = $this->createForm(ReclamationType::class, $reclamation);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $reclamationRepository->add($reclamation);
        return $this->redirectToRoute('reclamations_moi', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
    }

    return $this->render('home/reclamer_off.html.twig', [
        'reclamation' => $reclamation,
        'form' => $form->createView(),

    ]);
```

The `{id}` to `Offre` entity conversion is done by the SensioFrameworkExtraBundle, you may need to install that if you haven't got it yet: https://symfony.com/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/current/index.html

Or you could fetch the `Offre` entity manually:

```
/**
 * @Route("/offrerecla/recl/{id}", name="reclamation_new", methods={"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function nerjj(Request $request, ReclamationRepository $reclamationRepository, OffreRepository $offreRepository, $id): Response
{
    $offre = $offreRepository->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);

    $reclamation = new Reclamation();
    $reclamation->setOffre($offre);

    $form = $this->createForm(ReclamationType::class, $reclamation);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $reclamationRepository->add($reclamation);
        return $this->redirectToRoute('reclamations_moi', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
    }

    return $this->render('home/reclamer_off.html.twig', [
        'reclamation' => $reclamation,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Offre;
use App\Entity\Reclamation;
use App\Entity\User;
use DateTime;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;


class ReclamationType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): 
void
{
    $builder
        ->add('typereclamation')
        ->add('datereclamation',DateType::class, array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
            'data' => new \DateTime("today")
        ))
        ->add('descriptionrecla',TextareaType::class)
        ->add('comuniquer',TextareaType::class)
        ->add('etat',ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices'  => [
                'Rien' => 'Rien',
                'En cours' => 'En cours',
                'Traiter' => 'Traiter',
                'Non Traiter' => 'Non Traiter',
            ],
        ])
        ->add('cinreclameur',EntityType::class, [
            'class' => User::class,
            'choice_label' => 'cin',
        ])

        ->add('offreareclamer',EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Offre::class,
            'choice_label' => 'idoffre',
        ])

    ;
  }

   public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Reclamation::class,
    ]);
}
 }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
  * @Route("/offrerecla/recl/{id}", name="reclamation_new", methods={"GET", 
"POST"})
 */
public function nerjj(Request $request, ReclamationRepository 
$reclamationRepository, OffreRepository $offreRepository, $id): Response
{

    $offre = $offreRepository->findOneBy(['idoffre' => $id]);

    $reclamation = new Reclamation();
    $reclamation->setOffreareclamer($offre);
    $form = $this->createForm(ReclamationType::class, $reclamation);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $reclamationRepository->add($reclamation);
        return $this->redirectToRoute('reclamations_moi', [], 
  Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
    }

    return $this->render('home/reclamer_off.html.twig', [
        'reclamation' => $reclamation,
        'form' => $form->createView(),

    ]);
   }
```